# Automating React JS application with Protractor(Jasmine frame work)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, protractor

I have been using Protractor(Jasmine frame work) to automate Angular JS application. So i wanted to automate React JS application.
I have used Protractor(Jasmine frame work) to automate React JS application, but i faced lot of issues, had to use lot of explicit waits to visible the react web elements. Do we have any option to make it to wait until all the react web elements are visible
or
Please suggest the best way to automate React JS application

Answer (score 0):

Not possible in protractor at least

But I always use explicit waits even for angular applications because built-in protractor's waiting often is not stable

If you understand the correlation between API requests and loading of the application you'll have no problems. So basically reactjs is a library to build one page application which is loaded when you open the url. Once loaded and rendered in browser there is no more loading, unless an API request is sent. When that happens normally developers put up a loading animation. With that said, 95% of cases, you need to handle waiting in 2 cases: when the app is opening and when loading animaniton is up. If you create methods for that and put them in page objects library, your problem is solved with a few extra lins of code here and there